# Syntax error on the "N" on line 18

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax

I've been working on this simple program in Python just so I can start experimenting with Python and become more knowledgeable of Python and other programming languages in general by designing them in a way in which others can use them in an efficient manner without getting caught on the parts which make this code work. I've been doing this by having a simple program calculate "Angles in a triangle" as it's a simple subject. Recently, I replaced def(): commands with if statements as it cuts down typing to a minimum and making it generally easier for others however, when I try to run this code I get a syntax error message with N becoming highlighted on line 17.

```
def triangle():
    N = int(input("Please enter the number of angles you currently have between 1 and 3: "))
    if N == 1:
        a = int(input("What's one of the angles?"))
        b = int(input("What's the other angle in the triangle?"))
        c = a + b
        f = 180 - c
        print(f)
        print("If you'd like to continue, please type in triangle()")

    elif N == 2:
        a = int(input("What's the value of angle 1?"))
        b = 180 - a
        c = b /2
        print(c)
        print("If you'd like to continue, please type in triangle()")

    else N == 3:
        a = 180
        b = 180 / 3
        print(b)
        print("If you'd like to continue, please type in triangle()")
```

But I'm getting a syntax error returned on elif N == 3:
Any tips would be great.

Comment: 1. You don't actually have `elif N == 3`. 2. Please check the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/index.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `else N == 3:`. That is not how the `if..elif..else` structure works - the `else` is a catch-all branch that is entered if none of the preceding `if` or `elif` conditions are satisfied. If you want to check specifically for `N == 3` and no other values, use `elif N == 3`. If you want a catch-all condition, simply use `else:`.

Answer (score 2):

else does not have a condition.. remove it to just say

```
else:
```

or make it says

```
elif N == 3:
```

Answer (score 0):

```
elif N == 3:
```

Either you meant `elif` (which is Python for `else..if`), or `else`

If you meant plain `else`, it doesn't take a condition.

If you want to annotate that an `else` implies a certain condition is met, then I use a comment:

```
    else: # N == 3
```

But that's considered bad style: only do that if you're sure N cannot have any other value than 1,2,3. In your case the user could also input any number 4,5,..,9 (or indeed 10 or larger, or indeed 0 or any negative number), and that will wrongly get handled by the N==3 branch.

Whereas if your last branch if `elif N == 3`, with no `else`-clause, invalid numbers will silently fail every branch in your tree.
So for completeness and sanity-checking, you might prefer to do:

```
    ...
elif N ==3:
    # Handle N == 3 case
else:
    print "Invalid number!"
```

Comment: I always presumed that else: came at the end of an elif/if statement to show it's the end of it. Thanks.

Comment: @RichardAutoglassPope, no, you might be thinking of languages like Pascal and their obsession with 'BEGIN...END'. `else` is not just some boilerplate keyword that terminates an `if`-statement. The `else:` clause picks up every case which the `if..elif[...elif]` clauses did not pick up. That could be a large mixed-bag of stuff, as in this case, especially in a dynamically-typed language. N is not even guaranteed to be an integer; N could be a float, and if we were using numpy, N could be NaN (or +Inf, or -Inf)